# integral extensions and integral elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $B = K[u_1, \ldots, u_{n-1}]$ -- algebra ($K$ is the field, as usual), and $u_n$ -- is an integral element over $B$. Prove that algebra $A=B[u_n]$ is an integral extension of $B$, i.e. every element of $A$ is integral over $B$.

I guess, that the fact that $A$ is noetherian implies this somehow, but can't show it in a proper way.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

$B$ is a noetherian ring as a finitely generated k-algebra. $A$ is finitely generated module over $B$, thus if we have any $x \in A$ , then $B[x]$ (generated as an algebra) is also a finitely generated $B$-module (as $B[x]$ is submodule of $A$). Therefore, $B[x]$ is generated by finitely many $\{1, x, \ldots, x^{l-1}\}$ as a $B$-module. Thus, $x^l$ is $B$-linear combination of $\{1, x, \ldots, x^{l-1}\}$ and we are done.